# Azure function singleton mode and scope

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have been working on Azure Function Service bus with Topic.

I have following requirement

**Making the function invocations to be singleton at a host scope for all that cannot be run concurrently for some reason**

suggest me the best suited one and help me to understand the difference between them.

**MODES**

1. [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
2. [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Function)]

**SCOPES**

1. SingletonScope.Host
2. SingletonScope.Function

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please note the [Singleton] attribute currently does not work on the consumption plan currently. You must use app services plan. It fails silently. Watch out!

Comment: This is the official documentation. It's pretty detailed (except for not mentioning it won't work on consumption plan). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#scope-values

Comment: Thank you @simon-weaver.

Comment: Is there any way to see (logs or something) when it fails on the consumption plan?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Is there any source available where you got this information from and is it still valid for today?

Comment: @André sorry I only experimented with functions briefly, and they had too many issues without real benefit to me so I haven't touched anything in 2+ years. All I remember is what's in that link. I seem to remember communicating with someone at Azure but I'm not sure I could find it now.

Comment: To test I'd first try doing something like `await Task.Delay(30000)` inside the function and see what happens if I try to run it twice within 30 seconds.